# is it possible to scale an ImageView such that a LinearLayout below it is always completely visible?

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout is below. On some mdpi screens the inner LinearLayout is cutoff. What I would like to happen is to make sure that the inner LinearLayout always shows all of it's content. I would like the ImageView to scale down as small as it needs to make sure that the LinearLayout below it show's all of it's content. On large screens, the ImageView should be as large as it's image (i.e. `wrap_content`).

I tried giving the ImageView a `layout_weight` of 0.1 and the LinearLayout a `layout_weight` of 0.9 (and giving both of them a `layout_height` of 0dp), but then on larger screens the ImageView ends up being at the top of the layout. I would like the contents of the root LinearLayout to be centered.

So is it possible to make the ImageView shrink only if it needs to, such that the LinearLayout below it is always completely visible? I am trying to accomplish this witout creating multiple layout files for different screen sizes/resolutions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/tab_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".messages.MessagesHomeFragment"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/elephant_large" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send_voice_message"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send a Voice Message" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send_sms_message"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send an SMS" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_view_messages"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Manage Messages" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_invite_sms_recipients"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Invite SMS Recipients" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do by using the layout below. The key was to set the root LinearLayout's height to `wrap_content` and set the `layout_weight` of the ImageView to 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/tab_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/elephantImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/elephant_large"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send_voice_message"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send a Voice Message" />

        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is possible... if anything, I would try something like the layout described below (I did not try it, I am afraid the image would grow as much as it can with something like that). I only changed the layout attributes of the ImageView

If that still does not work, it should not be too difficult to define your own widget based on ImageView where you would only need to override the onLayout method to scale down only if  the measureSpec you get is smaller than the image...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/tab_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".messages.MessagesHomeFragment"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/elephant_large" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send_voice_message"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send a Voice Message" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send_sms_message"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send an SMS" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_view_messages"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Manage Messages" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_invite_sms_recipients"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Invite SMS Recipients" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```